# Apply jQuery Styling (.toggleClass) to Newly-Added DOM Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

So, I'm working on a webpage that has a small "notepad" widget, and I've updated the interface to work as follows:

1. The notepad is actually just a styled `<ul>` with each line on the notepad page as its own  `<li>`.
2. The user can simply click and type to add a new `<li>` because it is `contenteditable: true`.
3. Each newly added line is placed in a `<p>` element, and styled with jQuery.

Now here's my jQuery issue... The code below successfully adds the "strikethrough" class to the `<p>` element when double-clicked, and then removes it when double-clicked again. **HOWEVER**, if I click the "notepad" to add a new `<p>` element, the jQuery script below doesn't work. It only applies to `<p>` elements that were already on the page when the document loaded the first time.

```
// NOTEPAD INTERFACE
$(".paper p").dblclick( function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("strikethrough");
});
```

Does anybody know how to make the same jQuery apply to every `<p>` element equally, regardless of when it was added to the DOM?

Comment: search for event delegation in jQuery. You have to use `$('.paper').on('dblclick', 'p',function(){...})` instead.

Comment: @KingKing, That did it! If you'll submit that as an answer, I'll accept it gratefully!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.delegate()`. This will make your function be applied to every element, even the newly created ones:

```
$(".paper").delegate('p', 'dblclick', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("strikethrough");
});
```

[Here's the documentation for delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Comment: So what's the difference between your `.delegate()` solution and @KingKing 's `.on()` solution?

Comment: One is more backwards compatible than the other, however if you're not building plugins that is irrelevant.

Comment: @elersong `.on()` is the new stuff added as of jquery 1.7 (and replacing `delegate`), you can freely use it if you use jquery 1.7 (or above). of course this answer is also correct, so feel free to accept it, I won't add my own answer.

Comment: Exactly, it all comes down to backward compatibility